# How to install npm without curl | bash?

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

I know it is now customary to paste (or pipe!) shell scripts from webpages into ones root shell. In the recent past we called this "getting rooted" it was not something you did intentionally.

Source: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -

This security model requires you to trust: curl, the Node project, the authors of nodesource.com, Google's ranking of nodesource.com, other people that might control nodesource.com, various cryptographic infrastructure between your computer and nodesource.com (TLS 1.0 anybody?), and most importantly, the immutability (resource integrity) of the resource at https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x.

For important software, I am more used to trusting a distributor (Ubuntu) to review and validate these details for me.

Is there a better way to install npm for somebody that has more than a dog's level of understanding of computer security?

Comment: It's worth noting though that this primarily installs node which bundles npm.

Comment: Does the above include both?

Comment: `npm` comes bundled with `node` so yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did to install NodeJS 14 on Debian Bullseye:

1. Copy node's key from https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key
2. Paste this into a new file called `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nodejs.asc`
3. Run `echo "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x $(lsb_release -c -s) main"` to get the source entry. For me this was `"deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x bullseye main"`
4. Paste the source entry from step 3 to a new file called `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list`
5. `sudo apt update`
6. `sudo apt install nodejs`
7. Check it worked: `node -v`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to upgrade your Nodejs version:

1. navigate to this file; `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list`
2. change the version in the source entry from;

   deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x jammy main
   to;
   deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x jammy main
3. save the changes.
4. run sudo apt update
5. run sudo apt upgrade
6. check out the new versions of Nodejs and npm.

Thank you.